# Bootstrap Modal ajax content, animation loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I use the Bootstrap Modal by loading content from another page and that data is so complicated (multi query/dynamic form), so when open the modal, it will have a little bit stuck.

I want some animation or indicator to show that modal has not been crashed... please wait.

I have to search and try many ways but doesn't work, in some solution the .gif is stuck too when modal load. I use this method for remote content. http://jsfiddle.net/cp67J/1994/

```html
<!-- Link trigger modal -->
<a href="remote_content.php?id=1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
    Launch Modal content 1
</a>
<a href="remote_content.php?id=2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >
    Launch Modal content 2
</a>

<!--MODAL SECTION-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your JS code. Especially Ajax code

Comment: i just use only jquery.min.js & bootstrap.min.js for load the modal

Comment: I mean which js code cause this modal to be opened ? Are you using Ajax ?

Comment: nothing, see the example from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cp67J/1994/)

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if bootstrap modal supports this. But simple solution would be.

1. Show normal modal with loading animation.
2. Load your content with ajax in background.
3. Replace loader with loaded data.

P.S. you can also experiment with $.fn.load and allow jQuery to do 2. and 3. steps for you.